# Retrieve integer from Firebase child

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to implement a counter for deals in my app. i am trying to recall the last integer written to the child e.g. deal number 10. i can successfully write a manually inputted value into firebase however i cannot retrieve the initial value.

i am using the following

```
dealnumRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
val numberRef = dealnumRef.child("Total_deals").orderByChild("deal_number")


val dealnumEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        for (ds in dataSnapshot.children) {

            val deal_num =
                ds.child("deal_number_cars").getValue()
            d("current deal number",deal_num.toString())
            val new_deal_num = deal_num + 1
```

the issue i have is that currently `deal_num` is pulling through as `Any?`. If i insert `String::class.java` into `getvalue()`it will bring it back as a string. But I need to keep it as an `Integer` to compute `new_deal_num` because `new_deal_num` will need to be written to the database and increment the `deal_number` to 11 as an example.

how do i extract `deal_num` as an integer?

I have checked available answers, but those indicate to convert to string. This would not work in my example, because i need to increment the deal number and hence keep it as an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the correct type from Firebase by passing its class into `getValue(..)`.

So:

```
val deal_num = ds.child("deal_number_cars").getValue(Long.class)
```

If you're storing a number in `deal_number_cars` in the database, this will get that value as a `long`.

Comment: this still does't seem to help, getValue() doesn't seem to take Long.class as an argument. link to image showing error ibb.co/2cF6r2g

Comment: Should be `getValue(Long::class.java)`

Comment: Hi @PeterHaddad, your suggestion helped somewhat but still doesnt seem to extract the value. see error i am getting from the Logcat https://ibb.co/7t75P8d

Comment: Found the problem. i had to remove the reference to child("deal_number_cars"). this returned the value successfully.

Answer (score -1):

The Full correction to the above is as follows:

```
dealnumRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
val numberRef = dealnumRef.child("Total_deals").orderByChild("deal_number_cars")


val dealnumEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
    for (ds in dataSnapshot.children) {

        val deal_num =
            ds.getValue(Long::class.java)!!
        d("current deal number",deal_num.toString())
        val new_deal_num = deal_num + 1
```

You also have to make sure that you data model class is set as Long. i originally had it set as Int which created a small problem but was easily resolved.